# How to get the List URL in a SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I've gotten as far as below:

[image]

But I don't know what they want me to choose in the "Find the List Item" section.  I don't want anything from the list item... I want the URL of the list.  Suggestions?

**NOTE**  I actually have "Current List" selected for my Data source.  I was just trying something else out when I took the screen shot...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just see the screen shot below and select the **Current Item** there.

[image]

Comment: How the hell does this answer the question? How do you get the LISTURL from there?

Answer (score 1):

The "Current Item -> Path" gives you the site relative URL to the list it's in, and you can add the site URL in a string varable to embed it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Construct the URL manually in designer :

[image: Link to dispform.aspx in workflow]

1. Type the majority of the URL in manually : **http://server/site/list/DispForm.aspx?ID=**
2. Add or Change Lookup
3. Select Data source: **Current Item**
4. Select Field from source: **ID**
5. Final link will look like this: http://server/site/list/DispForm.aspx?ID=**[%Current Item:ID%]**

Comment: The limitation with this method is that if you have a DEV environment and a PRODUCTION environment, you'll have to remember to come in and update that hardcoded URL bit when you migrate to production.

Answer (score 0):

In SPD2010 there is a lookup that will give you the DispForm URL of the current Item.  The URL will display like this http://Server/Site/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

[image]

Comment: In designer 2013 this takes you directly to the item, rather than the dispform.